# Not able to convert date/time to current locale

Tags: c++builder, vcl

I am stuck trying to convert a date/time, which is read from a CSV file, into a format that is compatible with the current locale. The code has to run across different locales (for testing I have set the locale as Frisian (Netherlands)).

The date/time from the CSV is either `8/4/2022 10:13` or `05/16/2020 02:39:58`.

I tried using the date (from the CSV) to set `strStartDate` as `8/4/2022 10:13`, but the below code throws an `EConvertError` exception on the `StrToDateTime()` call:

```cpp
TFormatSettings formatSettings;

formatSettings.ShortDateFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy";
formatSettings.LongTimeFormat = "hh:mm:ss";
GetLocaleFormatSettings(LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, formatSettings);

TDateTime outdateBegin = StrToDateTime(strStartDate, formatSettings);
```

The exception I get has the message:

> '8/4/2022 10:13' is not a valid date and time

Any pointers on how to make the CSV date convert to a correct `TDateTime` format across different locales?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be populating the `TFormatSettings` with system defaults **before** you then customize its fields as needed.  In the code you have shown, you are filling it with defaults **after** you customize it, so you are losing your customizations.

Also, just an FYI, `StrToDateTime()` does not use the `TFormatSettings::LongTimeFormat` field at all.  That field is used when converting a `TDateTime` into a `String`, not the other way around.  `StrToDateTime()` uses `TFormatSettings::ShortTimeFormat` instead (but only when `SysLocale::FarEast` is `true` and `TFormatSettings::ShortDateFormat` contains `dddd`).

Try this instead:

```cpp
// INITIALIZE THE FORMAT FIRST...
TFormatSettings formatSettings;
GetLocaleFormatSettings(LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, formatSettings); // <-- moved here!
// alternatively:
// TFormatSettings formatSettings(LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT);

// THEN CUSTOMIZE THE FORMAT AS NEEDED...
formatSettings.ShortDateFormat = _D("mm/dd/yyyy");
formatSettings.DateSeparator = _D('/');
formatSettings.TimeSeparator = _D(':');

// THEN USE THE FORMAT...
TDateTime outdateBegin = StrToDateTime(strStartDate, formatSettings);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This works for me. The DateSeparator and TimeSeparator are new to me.

Comment: @Nijaguna refer to the [documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TFormatSettings) to learn about all of the available fields